# Why does using DISTINCT ON () at different points in a query return different (unintuitive) results?

Tags: postgresql

I’m querying from a table that has repeated uuids, and I want to remove duplicates. I also want to exclude some irrelevant data which requires joining on another table. I can remove duplicates and then exclude irrelevant data, or I can switch the order and exclude then remove duplicates. Intuitively, I feel like if anything, removing duplicates then joining should produce more rows than joining and then removing duplicates, but that is the opposite of what I’m seeing. What am I missing here?

In this one, I remove duplicates in the first subquery and filter in the second, and I get 500k rows:

```
with tbl1 as (
select distinct on (uuid) uuid, foreign_key
from original_data
where date > some_date
),

tbl2 as (
select uuid
from tbl1
left join other_data
on tbl1.foreign_key = other_data.id
where other_data.category <> something
)

select * from tbl2
```

If I filter then remove duplicates, I get 550k rows:

```
with tbl1 as (
select uuid, foreign_key
from original_data
where date > some_date
),

tbl2 as (
select uuid
from tbl1
left join other_data
on tbl1.foreign_key = other_data.id
where other_data.category <> something
),

tbl3 as (
select distinct on (uuid) uuid
from tbl2
)

select * from tbl3
```

Is there an explanation here?

Comment: Because you don't use `ORDER BY` - that way you do not get consistent results.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Unfortunately no :( same problem if I add an `ORDER BY uuid, date`

Comment: Hard to believe. Please provide sample data that exhibit the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Does `original_data.foreign_key` have a foreign key constraint referencing `other_data.id` allowing for `foreign_key`s that don't link to any `id` in `other_data`?

Isn't `other_data.category` or `original_data.foreign_key` column missing a `NOT NULL` constraint?

In either of these cases postgres would filter out all records with

1. a missing link (`foreign_key=null`)
2. a broken link  (`foregin_key` doesn't match any id in `other_data`)
3. linking to an `other_data` record with a category set o null

in both of your approaches - regardless of whether they're a duplicate or not - as `other_data.category <> something` evaluates to null for them which [does not satisfy the `WHERE` clause](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-select.html#SQL-WHERE). That, combined with missing `ORDER BY` causing `DISTINCT ON` to drop different duplicates [randomly](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT) each time, could result in dropping the duplicates that then get filtered out in `tbl2` in the first approach, but not in the second.
Example:

```
pgsql122=# select * from original_data;
 uuid | foreign_key |                      comment
------+-------------+---------------------------------------------------
    1 |           1 | correct, non-duplicate record with a correct link
    3 |           2 | duplicate record with a broken link
    3 |           1 | duplicate record with a correct link
    4 |        null | duplicate record with a missing link
    4 |           1 | duplicate record with a correct link
    5 |           3 | duplicate record with a correct link, but a null category behind it
    5 |           1 | duplicate record with a correct link
    6 |        null | correct, non-duplicate record with a missing link
    7 |           2 | correct, non-duplicate record with a broken link
    8 |           3 | correct, non-duplicate record with a correct link, but a null category behind it

pgsql122=# select * from other_data;
 id | category
----+----------
  1 | a
  3 | null
```

1. Both of your approaches keep uuid 1 and eliminate uuid 6, 7 and 8 even though they're unique.
2. Your first approach randomly keeps between 0 and 3 out of the 3 pairs of duplicates (uuid 3, 4 and 5), depending on which one in each pair gets discarded by `DISTINCT ON`.
3. Your second approach always keeps one record for each uuid 3, 4 and 5. Each clone with missing link, a broken link or a link with a null category behind it is already gone by the time you discard duplicates.

As [@a_horse_with_no_name](https://stackoverflow.com/users/330315/a-horse-with-no-name) suggested, `ORDER BY` should make `DISTINCT ON` consistent and predictable but only as long as records vary on the columns used for ordering. It also won't help if you have other issues, like the one I suggest.